# Trying to write a simple code in mongoldb, receiving an error

Tags: mongodb

Just trying out MongoDB. So this might be a very basic issue. Trying to create a collection "info", but encountering errors as below. Appreciate the help.

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
@(shell):1:42
```

The code is as below :

```
db.info.insert({"userName":"John","mail”:"John@gmail.com","mobile":12345678},{"Transaction":[{"itemId":"a100","price":200},{"itemId":"a110","price":200}]},{"Payment":["Type":"Credi
t-card","Total":400,"Success":true]},{"Remarks":"1st complete record,payment successful"})
```

Comment: Before writing a book, a person needs to know how to write a sentence.  Try to write the code for two or three variables first.  Try: db.info.insert({"userName":"John","mail”:"John@gmail.com","mobile":12345678}),  See if that works.  Is so, add some more variables.  If not, remove some variables and try again. If it doesn't work with one variable, then it can be assumed your are doing something wrong.

Comment: First occurance of string `"mail”:` has a wrong closing quotation sign (`”` instead of `"`). Is that an error in the code or just something that was introduced while moving the question to SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try, most of the developers would recommend to read the documentation of [Insert data in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/). If you clearly understand, then you might understand the problem. The document was not well formatted which means you created object for each `key:value` pair. And `payment` is an array which holds objects. It was also not formatted.

You can try below code, and have fun with MongoDB

```
db.info.insert(
{
    "userName":"John",
    "mail":"John@gmail.com",
    "mobile":12345678,
    "Transaction":[{"itemId":"a100","price":200},{"itemId":"a110","price":200}],
    "Payment":[{"Type":"Credit-card","Total":400,"Success":true}],
    "Remarks":"1st complete record,payment successful"
}
)
```

Comment: I will surely try this. Thank you for the clarification. I am very new to coding so this might have appeared extremely convoluted.